# Field widget do not save values in database!

Tags: 7, entities

I have a strange problem. I'm designing a new field type using field-API with a widget of course. 
My widget display is ok but when I save a node the field do not save the value entered in the widget..

This is the hook_field_schema()

```
function MODULE_field_schema($field) {
  $columns = array(
    'streamtype' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 25, 'not null' => FALSE),
    'streamtag' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 25, 'not null' => FALSE)
  );
  return array(
    'columns' => $columns,
  );
}
```

And this in the hook_field_widget_form()

```
function MODULE_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {

      switch ($instance['widget']['type']) {

        case 'MODULE_default_widget':
          $item = $items[$delta];

          $element += array(
            '#type' => 'fieldset',
            '#delta' => $delta,
            '#element_validate' => 'MODULE_field_basic_widget_validate'
          );

          $element['streamtype'] = array(
            '#type' => 'radios', 
            '#title' => t('Stream type.'),  
            '#description' => t('Search images by:'), 
            '#options' => array('author' => t('Author name'), 'tag' => t('Tag')), 
            '#weight' => isset($element['#weight']) ? $element['#weight'] : 0, 
            '#delta' => $delta,  
            '#default_value' => isset($item['streamtype']) ? $item['streamtype'] : NULL
          );

          $element['streamtag'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',  
            '#title' => t('Stream tag'),  
            '#description' => t('Insert author name or tag depending to the selected steam type'),  
            '#required' => $instance['required'],  
            '#weight' => isset($element['#weight']) ? ($element['#weight'] + 1) : 0, 
            '#delta' => $delta,    
            '#default_value' => isset($item['streamtag']) ? $item['streamtag'] : NULL
          );

          break;

      }

      return $element;
    }
```

The basic fieldset have a validation function and, in this one i can see the correct value in the $item.
An example from watchdog()

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [streamtype] => tag [streamtag] => tag1, tag2, tag3 ) )
```

Where can i search the error?
Please help me, this problem is driving me crazy T____T

Comment: I do lots of custom field work and I've never set #delta by hand. Maybe try and remove `'#delta' => $delta` from both the `$element` and the items `streamtype` and `streamtag`. Also, do you implement `hook_field_is_empty()`? Can you post the code for that?

Comment: Now it works!  
There was a naming error in hook_field_is_empty() ['straemtype' and not 'streamtype'] and I delete '#delta' => $delta

Thank you so much ^^
If you insert an answer i can flag it ^^

Comment: Related: [drupal field widget not saving submitted data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12433039/55075) at SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out Shyghar ran into an issue that I've run into more than I care to tell – which is that `hook_field_is_empty()` was returning FALSE by checking the wrong data (or something along those lines).